# Android, manipulating previous activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have got 2 activities - "A" contains fragment with a list of conversations, "B" represents a conversation (shows it's messages), in B I can also send a new message. 
I would like to be able to update A's list of conversations every time a message is sent in B, so when I click android's back button, A activity's view is updated.

The core of the problem for me, is that I'm not starting A through an Intent when I click the android's back button, so I don't know how to get this effect.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `i m not starting A through an Intent` . if A is an activity you must have started it with an intent. is it the Main Activity of your application?

Comment: In this case Activity A will be paused while Activity B is displayed.  Since only one Activity can be shown at any given time, it doesn't make sense to have communication between them.  What you should do is update your data source in Activity B, and in `onResume()` of Activity A, refresh/reload the data.

Comment: the best solution is using content providers

Comment: Option 1 - You can maintain a small SQlite database and keep updating and reading the conversations between Activity A and B. Even if the application stops and when you come back, all those things will remain there.

Comment: Option 2 -  You can pass parcelable objects. You might be starting Activity B using an intent. So start with startActivityForResult. On finish of Activity B, return parcelable data back to Activity A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When A is on the backstack, there's no guarantee that an instance of A even exists in memory.  The answer to the question of how to manipulate A from B is **don't**.

Some correct ways of doing it:

- If your model (the list of conversations) is `Parcelable` or `Serializable`, you can pass it between activities via `Intent`.  You can pass it back from B to A if you start B for result and retrieve it from the `Intent` returned to A's `onActivityResult`.
- Make the model persistent, like in a database or `SharedPreferences` file.
- Put the model in a bound `Service`.  This would be faster than having each activity load it from persistent storage, but you may still need to make it persistent so you don't lose it when the `Service` shuts down.